# Android limitation

Tags: android

I have one application in android when i run that application it shows that exception

```
09-13 16:38:25.049: WARN/dalvikvm(269): VFY: arbitrarily rejecting large method (regs=132 count=21332)

09-13 16:38:25.049: WARN/dalvikvm(269): VFY:  rejected Lcom/ExtraCharge/Calc;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V

09-13 16:38:25.059: WARN/dalvikvm(269): Verifier rejected class Lcom/ExtraCharge/Calc;
09-13 16:38:25.059: WARN/dalvikvm(269): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/ExtraCharge/Calc;)

09-13 16:38:34.883: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

09-13 16:38:34.999: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43f8da58 com.ExtraCharge/.Calc}
```

Do you have any solution for that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be of use:

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg86311.html